# Unity3d + google play games

Tags: unity3d, google-play-games

Скачал плагин google play games с гитхаба, залил в пустой проект, обновил все в SDK менеджере, создал приложение, создал сервис, выпустил игру, выпустил сервис, делаю лидерборд и получаю ошибку

> Invalid classname: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Как это исправить?

[image: Снимок экрана с диалоговым окном с сообщением об ошибке]

Answer (score 0):

1. Обновить Android Support Repository
2. Обновить Google Play Service
3. Убедиться, что в проекте не более одной копии jar'ника "play-services-xxx".

Comment: 1. Удалил и скачал заново. 2. Удалил и скачал заново. 3. Убедился. Проблема не ушла